# version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found

Tags: compiling, xilinx

When I am trying to execute my hdl file with iverilog, I am getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/ivl/ivl: /opt/Xilinx/Vivado/2015.3/lib/lnx64.o/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /usr/local/lib/ivl/ivl)
```

Same is the case when I am simulating in Xilinx.

I have tried everything in earlier posts but nothing seems to work. Also, when I do

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX
```

I get the following:

```
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_3.4.20
GLIBCXX_3.4.21
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

So I suppose the latest version is already present. Unable to figure out the solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd xilinx_path/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.orig
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.14 libstdc++.so.6
```

These solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I also had additional paths added to LD_LIBRARY_PATH which were causing trouble with unrelated tools (svn in my case).

I had:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64:/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/EDK/lib/lin64:/opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64:...etc...
```

The system is searching these before /usr/lib so it was finding the stale one from Xilinx.

To fix it I did:

```
cd /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/ISE/lib/lin64/
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.orig
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 libstdc++.so.6
```

and

```
cd /opt/Xilinx/14.7/ISE_DS/common/lib/lin64/
sudo mv libstdc++.so.6 libstdc++.so.6.orig
ln -s /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 libstdc++.so.6
```

There is no libstdc++.so.6 in the EDK directory, so that was enough.

I happen to be running on Centos 7, but this may be helpful info in general.