# Why is apt-get update not picking up recent versions of the package I need?

Tags: 12.04, apt, software-installation, glibc

I'm having trouble installing some software on Travis CI due to missing dependencies to specific versions of `libstdc++`.

> /usr/local/EnergyPlus-8-4-0/energyplus: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /usr/local/EnergyPlus-8-4-0/energyplus)
>
> /usr/local/EnergyPlus-8-4-0/energyplus: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.18' not found (required by /usr/local/EnergyPlus-8-4-0/libenergyplusapi.so.8.4.0)
>
> /usr/local/EnergyPlus-8-4-0/energyplus: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.19' not found (required by /usr/local/EnergyPlus-8-4-0/libenergyplusapi.so.8.4.0)

Following advice on other sites I did an update:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

Then:

```
$ sudo apt-get install -y libstdc++6

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

libstdc++6 is already the newest version.

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 144 not upgraded.
```

Finally:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIBCXX

GLIBCXX_3.4

GLIBCXX_3.4.1

GLIBCXX_3.4.2

GLIBCXX_3.4.3

GLIBCXX_3.4.4

GLIBCXX_3.4.5

GLIBCXX_3.4.6

GLIBCXX_3.4.7

GLIBCXX_3.4.8

GLIBCXX_3.4.9

GLIBCXX_3.4.10

GLIBCXX_3.4.11

GLIBCXX_3.4.12

GLIBCXX_3.4.13

GLIBCXX_3.4.14

GLIBCXX_3.4.15

GLIBCXX_3.4.16

GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

So the version I have isn't the latest, unlike in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699440/version-glibcxx-3-4-20-not-found). What do I need to do to get the versions I need?

Comment: You should not only run an `apt-get update`you as well should run an `apt-get dist-upgrade`. Looking at 144 not upgraded packages is I assume the source of your evil.

Comment: 12.04 is not going to upgrade gcc past what it had at release ( gcc-4.6) Best option would be to go to 14.04

Comment: @doug thanks, that fixed it for me. I didn't realise that was as far as gcc went on 12.04

Answer (score 0):

To make sure that you are as up-to-date as you can be you should run:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

But if you still do not get the versions of the packages you need, then you will just have to face the fact that the developers of those packages didn't make them available for your version of Ubuntu and that you should upgrade (`do-release-upgrade`) to a later version in order to receive those versions. You could also find the source code for the relevant versions and then manually compile from source.